# How sigaction() differs from signal()?

Tags: tty, signals, pty

`prog2` does not exit on `CTRL+D`. Why `prog1` exits on `CTRL+D` then? More strange is that the signal handler does not perform any action, although it influences the end result somehow...

The following two programs differ only with that in `prog1.c` `sigaction()` is used, and in `prog2.c` `signal()` is used:

```
@@ -39,10 +39,7 @@
     /* read from loopback tty */
     if (cpid > 0) {
         /* this is the strange part */
-        struct sigaction sa;
-        sa.sa_handler = child_handler;
-        sa.sa_flags = 0;
-        sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);
+        signal(SIGCHLD, child_handler);

         struct termios tty;
         tcgetattr(fd, &tty);
```

Each of this programs simply opens a loopback tty and splits itself into two processes, one of which reads response from tty, and another writes data to tty device. The data received from the loopback tty virtual device is then output to the controlling terminal.

Compile `prog1` and `prog2` using `-lutil` option. Start each program and type `hello<CTRL+D>`. This results in the following output:

```
$ ./prog1
hello$

$ ./prog2
hello
```

BTW, which flags should be set in `sigaction()` to duplicate the behavior of `signal()`?

---

Here are the programs:

**prog1.c**

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pty.h>

int fd;

void child_handler(int s)
{
    (void) s;
}

int main(void)
{
    char c;

    /* open loopback tty device */
    pid_t lpid;
    lpid = forkpty(&fd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (lpid == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }
    if (lpid == 0) {
        char *args[] = { "cat", NULL };
        execv("/bin/cat", args);
    }

    /* create parallel process */
    pid_t cpid;
    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) {
        close(fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* read from loopback tty */
    if (cpid > 0) {
        /* this is the strange part */
        struct sigaction sa;
        sa.sa_handler = child_handler;
        sa.sa_flags = 0;
        sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);

        struct termios tty;
        tcgetattr(fd, &tty);
        cfmakeraw(&tty);
        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty);

        while (read(fd, &c, 1) != -1)
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, 1);
    }

    /* write to loopback tty */
    if (cpid == 0) {
        struct termios stdtio_restore;
        struct termios stdtio;
        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &stdtio_restore);
        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &stdtio);
        cfmakeraw(&stdtio);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &stdtio);

        while (1) {
            read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
            if (c == 0x04) break;
            write(fd, &c, 1);
        }

        tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &stdtio_restore);
        close(fd);
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**prog2.c**

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pty.h>

int fd;

void child_handler(int s)
{
    (void) s;
}

int main(void)
{
    char c;

    /* open loopback tty device */
    pid_t lpid;
    lpid = forkpty(&fd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (lpid == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }
    if (lpid == 0) {
        char *args[] = { "cat", NULL };
        execv("/bin/cat", args);
    }

    /* create parallel process */
    pid_t cpid;
    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) {
        close(fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* read from loopback tty */
    if (cpid > 0) {
        /* this is the strange part */
        signal(SIGCHLD, child_handler);

        struct termios tty;
        tcgetattr(fd, &tty);
        cfmakeraw(&tty);
        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty);

        while (read(fd, &c, 1) != -1)
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, 1);
    }

    /* write to loopback tty */
    if (cpid == 0) {
        struct termios stdtio_restore;
        struct termios stdtio;
        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &stdtio_restore);
        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &stdtio);
        cfmakeraw(&stdtio);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &stdtio);

        while (1) {
            read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
            if (c == 0x04) break;
            write(fd, &c, 1);
        }

        tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &stdtio_restore);
        close(fd);
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in behavior is likely because `signal` behaves as if the `SA_RESTART` flag was set on `sigaction`.  From the [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) manual page:

> The BSD semantics are equivalent to calling sigaction(2) with the
>   following flags:
>
> ```
> sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
> ```
>
> The situation on Linux is as follows:
>
> - The kernel's signal() system call provides System V semantics.
> - By default, in glibc 2 and later, the signal() wrapper function does not invoke the kernel system call.  Instead, it calls
>     sigaction(2) using flags that supply BSD semantics...

When the `SA_RESTART` flag is used some system calls are automatically restarted. When it is not used the call will return an error with errno set to `EINTR`.

Thus in the "read from loopback" process in `prog1` the following happens:

1. Your process is blocked in `read`
2. It receives SIGCHLD and runs the handler.
3. The `read` system call it was blocked in returns -1
4. The loop exits based on the `while` condition and the process exits.

In `prog2`, the `SA_RESTART` behavior means that after the signal handler is run in (2), the `read` call is restarted.

To make `prog1` behave like `prog2`, set `SA_RESTART`:

```
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
```

See the "Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers" section of the [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) manual page for more detail on `SA_RESTART`'s behavior.